# Is the IsNullOrEmpty bug fixed in .NET 3.0 or later?

Tags: c#, clr, jit, nullreferenceexception

Does anyone know if the IsNullOrEmpty bug is fixed in 3.0 or later? I currently came across the (NullReferenceException) bug in 2.0 and I have found documentation stating that is supposed to be fixed in the next release, but no definitive answer.

Comment: I'm not aware of any such bug.  Do you have a link to a report from connect.microsoft.com for reference?

Comment: download .NET 3.0 SDK, it's free, then test it

Comment: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=113102

Comment: Fixed in 06. Either you're way out of date or you are looking at a different bug.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found some [info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(VS.80).aspx) on the matter:

> This bug has been fixed in the
>   Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 Service
>   Pack 1 (SP1).

Answer (score 4):

Works with .NET 3.5SP1. Test program for those who want to try it (mostly taken from bug report):

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("starting");
      ShowBug(null);
      Console.WriteLine("finished");
      Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void ShowBug(string x)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
            {
                //TODO:
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Compile with /o+ /debug- from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has reported this bug as fixed [on the Connect site](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=113102&wa=wsignin1.0).  If you can still repro the issue, I encourage you to resubmit the regression.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on where you came across this bug also.  If you encountered it in a table adapter for instance it is because the properties themselves are set to return that exception when a value is null.